# outlook2010 VSTO addin forwardmail issue

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Am new in outlook add-in . I just create a encrypt and decrypt add-in using c#.
Now am facing a problem, when i decrypt the email, its open through mailitem_open function successfully . Then click the forward option and send email. Then close the window the actual message shown in decrypt mode not in encrypt one. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

When you click the Forward button or just call the [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865399(v=office.15).aspx) method a new item is created/returned. You need to encrypt it before sending/saving. For example:

```
Sub RemoveAttachmentBeforeForwarding()  
 Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myattachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector 
 If Not TypeName(myinspector) = "Nothing" Then 
  Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem.Forward 
  Set myattachments = myItem.Attachments 
  While myattachments.Count > 0 
   myattachments.Remove 1 
  Wend 
  myItem.Display 
  myItem.Recipients.Add "Eugene Astafiev" 
  myItem.Send 
 Else 
  MsgBox "There is no active inspector." 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok i understand when forward click new item is created, but the parent mail in inbox is changed